# ntpd gets "connect: invalid argument" on 0.0.0.2

Tags: ip-address, ntpd

It appears the reply for pool.ntp.org changed recently. This is making my CentosOS 6 ntp servers unhappy.

```
$ host pool.ntp.org
pool.ntp.org has address 0.0.0.2
pool.ntp.org has address 83.209.8.142
pool.ntp.org has address 130.236.254.17
pool.ntp.org has address 195.178.181.98

$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ntp_time -H pool.ntp.org
can't create socket connection#

$ strace -f /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ntp_time -H pool.ntp.org
...
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(123), sin_addr=inet_addr("83.209.8.142")}, 16) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(123), sin_addr=inet_addr("130.236.254.17")}, 16) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(123), sin_addr=inet_addr("195.178.181.98")}, 16) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) = 5
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(123), sin_addr=inet_addr("83.209.8.142")}, 16) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) = 6
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(123), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.2")}, 16) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6571c5b000
write(1, "can't create socket connection", 30can't create socket connection) = 30
exit_group(3)                           = ?
+++ exited with 3 +++
```

It appears that there is general agreement on this, as modern Ubuntu says:

```
$ ping 0.0.0.2
connect: Invalid argument
```

I thought 0.0.0.2 is a valid IP?

**UPDATE**

The issue is indeed periodic and has been going on for several days (since 2015-12-20 according to my nagios):

```
[12:40] host pool.ntp.org
pool.ntp.org has address 194.71.144.71
pool.ntp.org has address 79.136.86.176
pool.ntp.org has address 83.209.8.142
pool.ntp.org has address 178.73.198.130
[13:09] host pool.ntp.org
pool.ntp.org has address 194.71.144.71
pool.ntp.org has address 0.0.0.2
pool.ntp.org has address 178.73.198.130
pool.ntp.org has address 192.36.143.130
```

I suppose there is a ranking battle of some sort going on.

**UPDATE 2**

For those interested, this issue occurs when DNS RRs for pool.ntp.org is queried from Sweden.

Comment: maybe just a DNS hick-up. After entering *pool.ntp.org* in a browser I landed here: [sim720.co.uk](http://www.sim720.co.uk/#!menu). The address bar has shown http://pool.ntp.org/#!menu though.

Comment: @klanomath `pool.ntp.org` is only for NTP. If some of the servers in the pool happen to also be hosting HTTP, it is likely to be totally unrelated to NTP. And it is a reasonable practice to configure an HTTP server to redirect requests for unexpected domain names to a domain name which is supposed to be used with HTTP. So when things are behaving properly you can expect `http://pool.ntp.org/` to give you an error or send you to a more or less random site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of `0.0.0.0/8` is reserved, so that definitely isn't a valid IP for an ntp server. You can check the [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml) for more information.

You should file a few bug reports. One against `pool.ntp.org`, because they should be verifying the validity of IP addresses before allowing them into the pool. And one against `check_ntp_time`, because it shouldn't die even if an invalid address shows up. Instead it should try the three valid IP addresses it got.

Answer (score 10):

Of the four servers you list, three are in the pool and have valid server monitoring pages:

http://www.pool.ntp.org/scores/83.209.8.142

http://www.pool.ntp.org/scores/130.236.254.17

http://www.pool.ntp.org/scores/195.178.181.98

The other, illegal, one, does not:

http://www.pool.ntp.org/scores/0.0.0.2

As kasperd notes, the RRs returned on that A record are round-robin load-balanced, so we cannot tell whether your upstream DNS was lying to you, or an illegal address temporarily made it into the pool.  I know from experience as a pool admin that one's server has to be highly-available, and thus well-scored by the monitoring system, to be included in the pool.  So I personally doubt that an unreachable address could make it into the pool, and suspect that this was an upstream DNS glitch.  But unless you can reliably reproduce the result, I doubt we'll ever know.

It occurs to me that if `pool.ntp.org` used DNSSEC signatures, we would immediately be able to tell if this was a cache poisoning issue, or a crap-in-the-pool issue.  If I have a few spare minutes, I might raise the issue on the pool servers' admins' list.

**Edit**: I have raised the issue [on the admins list](http://lists.ntp.org/pipermail/pool/2015-December/007714.html), and have already had one independent confirmation that this address *does* seem to be making it into the pool, even though it clearly shouldn't.  Watch this space, I guess.

**Edit 2**: apparently, [this was a genuine bug and it has now been fixed](http://lists.ntp.org/pipermail/pool/2015-December/007721.html).  I agree with kasperd that it's worth chasing the plugin's authors to make the plugin more robust to crap in the pool.

Comment: Connecting to `0.0.0.0` on a Linux machine will connect you to localhost. So if you did monitor the availability of an NTP server on `0.0.0.0` it would probably appear to be highly available. There could be OS where this would be the case for any address in `0.0.0.0/8`. It would be a flawed design to rely on the availability monitoring to filter out invalid IP addresses. Those have to be filtered out before handing them to the monitoring.

Comment: That is also true of `127.0.0.1`, so I'm sure there is some filtering other than availability checking.  But even if there **weren't**, `0.0.0.2` isn't reachable the same way, so wouldn't pass the availability test.  I agree there could be an OS that violated the RFCs and handled `0.0.0.2` as you describe.  But there could equally be an OS that ignored all RFCs and passed any combination of characters as a valid IP address - and it probably wouldn't get used as the basis of an internet infrastructural service.

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.2 is "valid" per se but may only be used as a *source* address according to [RFC1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700) hence you cannot ping it.

Comment: `pool.ntp.org` uses DNS for load balancing. The answers you get will depend on your location, and they will change frequently.

Comment: You are right. I will drop that part of the answer.